# CentOS 7 won't serve static https content, why not?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, https, firewalld

I just re-installed `httpd` and created a static `index.html` file.  I have `firewalld` configured to allow internet access to the `https` service.  But when I type `https://my.server.ip` in a web browser, the browser gives an error saying it cannot connect with the server.  **What do I have to change in order for the browser to receive the `index.html` file?**

Here is the `firewalld` definition for the public zone:

```
[username@my.server.ip]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (default, active)
  interfaces: enp3s0
  sources: 
  services: https ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Here is the `index.html` file along with its location:

```
[username@my.server.ip]# cd /var/www/html
[username@my.server.ip html]# cat index.html
<html>
<body>
Understand that this is a test.  If this text appears in the browser, then https is working.
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the `VirtualHost` tag in `httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost server.ip.address:443>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
   SSLEngine on
   SSLProxyEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
   # ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
   # ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

[Here is a link](https://jumpshare.com/v/RhYEMKWdzUCGoApIE7AY?b=7HGxfhT9KQzJW5Xdkxfb) to the entire httpd.conf file.

**EDIT #1**

I am getting mixed results when I look to see what ssl is installed in the system.  For example, nothing is listening on 443.  Also, while systemctl cannot find openssl, yum seems to think that opensl is already installed.  But I did confirm that the .crt files are all in their intended locations.

```
[root@1my-server-ip-addr ~]# netstat -na | grep 443.*LISTEN
[root@1my-server-ip-addr ~]# systemctl status openssl
openssl.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

[root@1my-server-ip-addr ~]# yum install openssl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.chkhosting.com
 * epel: mirror.nexcess.net
 * extras: ftpmirror.your.org
 * updates: centos.mbni.med.umich.edu
Package 1:openssl-1.0.1e-34.el7_0.6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

**EDIT #2**

I also checked for mod_ssl and httpd status as follows:

```
[root@1my-server-ip-addr certs]# systemctl status mod_ssl.service
mod_ssl.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

[root@1my-server-ip-addr certs]# systemctl status httpd
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2014-12-11 18:44:31 EST; 1h 54min ago
 Main PID: 4094 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 0; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─4094 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4095 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4096 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4097 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4098 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─4099 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Dec 11 18:44:31 1my-server-ip-addr.static.servdns.com systemd[1]: Started The Apac...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

**EDIT #3**

I also tried the following, as per prateek61's advice:

```
[root@1my-server-ip-addr certs]# error_log
-bash: error_log: command not found
[root@1my-server-ip-addr certs]# access_log
-bash: access_log: command not found
[root@1my-server-ip-addr certs]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

**EDIT #4**

I found the following in access_log.  I am not sure how to interpret it because a lot of cinfigurations have been changed today, and some of these logs may have been generated under different configurations:

```
[Thu Dec 11 15:37:59.025223 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2627] AH00170:  caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu Dec 11 16:40:07.114619 2014] [mime:error] [pid 981] (2)No such file or directory: AH01597: could not open mime types config file /etc/httpd/conf/mime.types.
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Thu Dec 11 16:43:30.051125 2014] [mime:error] [pid 1076] (2)No such file or directory: AH01597: could not open mime types config file /etc/httpd/conf/mime.types.
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Thu Dec 11 18:44:31.845012 2014] [suexec:notice] [pid 4094] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Dec 11 18:44:31.891627 2014] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 4094] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Dec 11 18:44:31.893061 2014] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 4094] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Dec 11 18:44:31.898347 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4094] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 11 18:44:31.898394 2014] [core:notice] [pid 4094] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

**EDIT #5**

I ran `yum remove mod_ssl httpd` and then `yum install mod_ssl httpd`.  I then opened my web browser and requested `https server.ip.addr` and got the same failure to connect message.  However, the following logs were created:

`access_log`

```
::1 - - [11/Dec/2014:21:47:42 -0500] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-"  "Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [11/Dec/2014:21:47:42 -0500] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [11/Dec/2014:21:47:42 -0500] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [11/Dec/2014:21:47:42 -0500] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [11/Dec/2014:21:47:42 -0500] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) (internal dummy connection)"
```

error_log

```
[Thu Dec 11 21:47:42.930487 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4094] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
```

There were no changes to `ssl_access_log`, `ssl_error_log` or `ssl_request_log`.

I do not know if some of the new logs were created by the act of un-installing and then re-installing.

---

**Partial Answer**

Three steps got `httpd` to serve the `index.html` page when requested via `https my.server.ip`:

```
1.) yum remove mod_ssl httpd  
2.) yum install mod_ssl httpd  
3.) systemctl restart httpd.service
```

But closer examination showed that removal of the `VirtualHost` directive and the `Listen 443` from `httpd.conf` played a role in getting the static content to be served.  When I added the `VirtualHost` directive back in, a new error was thrown.

I need the `VirtualHost` directive because the end goal is to serve up `war` files from `tomcat` when an `https` request for a given domain comes in from a web browser.

I did not try to put `Listen 443` back into `httpd.conf` because a similar `Listen` directive is given in `ssl.conf`.

Comment: Does it work if you use regular HTTP?

Comment: What do you get for `netstat -na | grep 443.*LISTEN`?

Comment: log files, if selinux is enabled, etc.

Comment: Have you installed `mod_ssl`?
Also, what is the output of `systemctl status httpd`?

Comment: Try a `yum install mod_ssl`?
Then restart `httpd` and then try. Ensure that the files are in the correct locations. Also what is your output of `sestatus`?

Comment: Hmm, so from this point I would look at the following. The output of `error_log`, `access_log` and the output of `sestatus`. Those should give you at least a semblance of what is happening with apache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19414/discussion-between-prateek61-and-codemed).

Comment: OK - not sure why that is. But in any case, log files are stored in the `/var/log/httpd/` directory. You should review the files to see if there is anything amiss there. You can also try following along here: http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=httpd&f=7 if you want a guide.

Comment: Why not take a look in the files your self. If there is something amiss post the relevant lines. See if there is a failed to start in those logs.

Comment: At this point I would try tearing down your httpd setup and building it from scratch. There are a lot of possible issues here so you might have your best bet to build back from the ground up.

Comment: Can you try and `yum remove mod_ssl httpd` and then a `yum install mod_ssl httpd`? Then start the services again and instead configuring the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` file?

Comment: What is the output of a `netstat -tunlp`?

Comment: Glad it worked - not sure if I actually provided a solution however. So I would be unwilling to post that as an answer :).

Answer (score 0):

You commented out the proxy listening on port 8080 in your above example.
Is there a (reverse)proxy configured and still listening on the front end?
In that case you should enable ssl on the front-end server and uncomment listening on 8080 as per your above example.

If there is no front-end proxy listening yet/at all: Make sure to to have ssl.conf configured again as you removed and reinstalled as per your description - which also removed the previously configured values and path to certs (which you created how?).

restart httpd and check syntax with `httpd -t`.
If that returns Syntax OK I recommend a ping to see if that is going through at all. Should that be the case, pls. share your ssl.conf